# Determine whether a is a factor of b

Tags: java

> Given two integers, a and b, check to see whether a is a factor of b. If a is an integer of b, return true. If not, return false.
>
> Inputs:
>  
>   a and b - two integers, where a is a potential factor and b is an integer larger than or equal to a; a is going to always be less than or equal to b
>
> Output:
>  
>   boolean - true if a is a factor of b, false if not

Here's what I tried:

```
boolean factor( int a, int b ) {
    int divider = a%b;
    if (divider == 0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i do not know what i did wrong

Comment: How do you know that you did something wrong? What does your code do? Why did you write it this way? How does it attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have your mod statement backwards if you want `a` to be the smaller number.

```
int divider = b%a;
```

Answer (score 1):

To know if b can be divided by a (with 0 remainder):

```
boolean factor( int a, int b ) {
    return b % a == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isFactor(int potential, int number) {
    return number%potential== 0;
}
```

This should solve your problem.  You had the order in your modulus wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Start with tests, then implement them. You want to test the 0 case.

```
@Test
public void test(){
    assertFalse(factor(5,6));
    assertTrue(factor(4,2));
    assertFalse(factor(8,0));
    assertTrue(factor(0,9));
}

public boolean factor(int a, int b){
    if(b == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return a % b == 0;
}
```